# $\lfloor\log{p_{n}}\rfloor$ having more than one solution for individual $k$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-writing, logarithms

**Question:**
If you assume that

a. $k\in\Bbb{N}$

b. $p_n$ denotes the $n$'th prime number. $p_0$ doesn't exist.

c. $n\in\Bbb{N}$

I am fairly certain that:

At least two distinct integer values for $n$ satisfy $\lfloor\log{p_n}\rfloor=k$ for any $k\geqslant 2$

I am looking for a proof that conjecture.

**Attempts:** I have done two things and then I hit my roadblock. (It is amazingly hard to elaborate on them because I am on my iPhone here)

a) I have managed to prove that there are at least one solution for each $k$ by comparing the behavior of $\log$
and $\sqrt[3]{/space}. I used this [paper][1].

b) I also used the brute force method.  Going up to $k=777$, there are at least two $n$ solutions.

Thanks for any help.

[1][http://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.2113v2.pdf]

Comment: What is the base of your $\log$?

Comment: @Wojowu Log on its own denotes the natural log

Comment: Once you take the floor you automatically get an integer.  So, if I am interpreting your requirements correctly, your property holds for all $n$ such that $\log(p_n) \geq 2$ (not just two $n$).

Comment: @Apple I have encountered a convention (which is quite common where I live) that sole $\log$ denotes decimal logarithm. Although I know it's more common to use it for natural log, I asked in order to clarify that.

Comment: If you want $\lfloor \log(p_n) \rfloor = \lfloor \log(p_{n+1})\rfloor$, then solutions are very eash to find, like 11 and 13.

Comment: @Michael I'm afraid you are misinterpreting my question. In more lax terminology, you give me a number, I give you back at least two other numbers n such that $\floor{p_n} fits the number you gave.

Comment: @Michael In a third means of explaining: for every k >= 2, there are at least 2 n that fit it.

Comment: What the hell am I saying? It's his question. I just get what he's trying to say.

Comment: @Michael what Apple said is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Use strengthenings of Bertrand's Postulate, in particular [Nagura's result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results) that for $n\ge 25$ there is always a prime between $n$ and $n\left(1+\frac{1}{5}\right)$.  We can use this to show that unless $k$ is very small, there are always at least $4$ distinct primes $p$ that satisfy $\lfloor \log p \rfloor=k$.